# How can I create my own survey like a form page by inheriting Odoo's(odoo-15) survey module?

Tags: python, web, view, erp, odoo-15

I want to create my own survey by inheriting odoon's customer survey module. However, I want the questions of the survey to be displayed in the view as a form. I inherited the module with the following code blog. However, I want to customize this module for myself and I want to edit the views, how can I do this?

My Modul .py

```
from odoo import models, fields, api

class CustomSurvey(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'survey.survey'
```

My View .py

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <record id="action_custom_survey" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">Custom Surveys</field>
            <field name="res_model">survey.survey</field>
            <field name="view_mode">tree,form,kanban</field>
    </record>

    <menuitem id="menu_survey"
            name="Surveys"
            parent="menu_custom_survey"
            action="action_custom_survey"/>
</odoo>
```

I want to create my own survey by inheriting odoon's customer survey module. However, I want the questions of the survey to be displayed in the view as a form. I inherited the module with the following code blog. However, I want to customize this module for myself and I want to edit the views, how can I do this?

Comment: How should your view xml look like?